# What is the right typescript definition for a specific javascript instantiation pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, new-operator, instantiation, typescript-definitions

I'm currently working on `Paper.js` library typescript definition and I have trouble finding the right way to document some parts of the API.

The case can be reduced to the following: let's say we have an `Animal` class which has a static property `Dog` that is used as a custom constructor for the class:

```
var Animal = function(type) {};
Animal.Dog = function() {
    return new Animal('dog');
};
```

An `Animal` instance can be built in 2 ways:

```
var dog = new Animal('dog');
```

Or:

```
var dog = new Animal.Dog();
```

In both cases, I need the type of the `dog` variable to be inferred as `Animal`.

---

I first tried:

```
declare class Animal
{
    constructor ( type )
    static Dog (): Animal
}
```

But TSLint fails with the error: "Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.", because `Animal.Dog()` function return type is `Animal`.

And if I set the return type of `Animal.Dog()` as `void`:

```
declare class Animal
{
    constructor ( type )
    static Dog (): void
}
```

TSLint pass but I get `void` as the inferred type...

---

So I tried another way:

```
declare class Animal
{
    constructor ( type )
}

declare namespace Animal
{
    export class Dog extends Animal
    {
        constructor()
    }
}
```

With this, TSLint pass but in the case of:

```
var dog = new Animal.Dog();
```

The inferred type of `dog` variable is `Animal.Dog` and not `Animal` as I would want to.

That's not a big problem because `Animal.Dog` type extends `Animal` but there is no `Animal.Dog` in the library so I found this workaround misleading for the user.

Does anyone know a better way to handle this case ?

### Edit

Elaborating from @stramski solution, I add to the problem, the fact that `Animal.Dog` can have multiple signatures (e.g. `Animal.Dog()` and `Animal.Dog(color)`) and my goal is to document them separately.

Comment: With the last example, i believe you can force the use of the Animal type with `var dog: Animal = new Animal.Dog();`

Comment: @dotconnor - You can, but it's a maintenance hazard. You have to remember to do it every time.

Comment: What about not using the `new` keyword? Or is that too confusing if you mixed up Dog and Animal a lot?

Comment: @dotconnor - This is dictated by Paper.js rather than the OP, for instance [`Shape.Circle`](http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/#shape-circle-object). (Personally I think it's poor practice to document that you call that via `new`, but they do...)

Comment: @t-j-crowder, yes, that's exactly the problem :). My goal is to create a type definition for the API as it is. Even if some parts of it seem weird...

Comment: Typically when you are subclassing, there are concepts which are updated or overridden.  both Dog and Cat are animals, but they would override communicate with a "bark" or "meow" string.  So that being said, i think keeping things a bit more separate is more ideal.  `class Animal{ constructor(){}} class Dog extends Animal { constructor(){ super(); } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
declare class Animal
{
    constructor ( type )
    static Dog : (new () => Animal)
}
```

### Edit

As there are overloaded constructors the typing is a little different:

```
declare class Animal
{
    constructor ( type )
    static Dog : (new () => Animal) & (new (color) => Animal)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's far better then my actual workaround as it doesn't need an extra namespace declaration ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Experimenting with this, I found that my problem is a bit wider than what I originally asked for: in my case, static constructor can have multiple signatures e.g. [Shape.Circle(center, radius)](http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/#shape-circle-center-radius) and [Shape.Circle(object)](http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/#shape-circle-object).
Do you have an idea of how I could extend your idea to this case ?

Comment: You can pass arguments to the constructor-function. So for the Shape.Circle method the typing is: static Circle: (new (obj: object) => Shape) & (new (radius: number, center: number) => Shape);

Comment: This is perfect for the type, thanks.
The only trade of is that there can be only one comment for all the signatures but I guess that's a minor problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are subclassing..  Keeping things clean and concise is important.  In the way written above, you can see that Dog was created an animal, but it has no differences than being an animal.   In some cases, there are some variables or methods which are overridden.  That being said, I find it better if you implemented something akin to:

```
class Animal {
  constructor(){}
  communicate() { return "Makes Noise"; }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  communicate() { return "Barks"; }
}
```

from there you can override methods or variables in order to properly differentiate a Dog from Animal, from other Animal sub classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that you misunderstood the problem. All the point is that I have to create a type definition for a `JavaScript` specific implementation which is not using subclassing and in which a `Dog` class has no sense. `Animal.Dog` is just a static method used to instantiate the `Animal` class in a shortcut way. The definition you are proposing doesn't actually allow doing `var dog = new Animal.Dog();` which is what I want to do...

Comment: I was trying to understand the problem for you, i didnt see the requirement of no subclassing because my implementation above, a Dog IS-A Animal.  Since you said animal is a class, and not a container it implied subclassing because there would be methods involved and you wouldnt want to necessarily couple 1 subdefinition to a parent object.  Its all good, np.